# Is there an audio web_accessible_resource for Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to insert audio into a webpage via a Chrome extension. I know that to do this with images you must add `"images/my-image-file"` to the `web_accessible_resources` list in the manifest. However, after some searching online, there does not appear to be an equivalent of this for sound files. So, how would I insert audio to a webpage with my chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction that prevents you from including you audio files in  the [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) list in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).  That list can contain *whatever* resources you want to make accessible to content pages.

For example, if you want to make all files in your `myAudioFileDirectory` folder available in addition to some file called `bogusFileName.foobar` you could include them as:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "myAudioFileDirectory/*",
    "bogusFileName.foobar"
],
```

When you include `"images/my-image-file"` (as mentioned in your question), the fact that the images are in a directory called `images` is merely organization which you have chosen to use within your extension. It is not required that all images be placed in a directory called `images`. That is just the way it is commonly done, particularly in examples.